# Destination Weather API for REST API not returning JSON data in postman

Tags: java, json, rest, postman, openweathermap

I am Creating a REST API in java and testing it in postman and in the database have the latitude and longitude, I am trying to use the OpenWeather API to return weather data based on the latitude and longitude. however, when testing it in postman it is returning an HTML and not the JSON data I requested.

the path I am trying to test is

```
http://localhost:8080/Assignment2C/map/weather/4
```

the code in my controller is

```
  @GetMapping(value = "weather/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String getWeather(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        BreweriesGeocode geocode = geocode_service.getGeocode(id);
        Breweries brewerie = breweries_service.getBrewerieById(id);

        double latitude = geocode.getLatitude();
        double longitude = geocode.getLongitude();
       String output = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "&appid=4a1f5501b2798f409961c62d384a1c74";
       return output;
```

when using Postman it returns this

```
https: //api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=59.74509811401367&lon=10.213500022888184&appid=4a1f5501b2798f409961c62d384a1c74
```

but when I test the path that postman produces in the browser

```
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=59.74509811401367&lon=10.213500022888184&appid=4a1f5501b2798f409961c62d384a1c74
```

it returns the correct JSON data

which is

```
{"coord":{"lon":10.21,"lat":59.75},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":291.36,"feels_like":289.49,"temp_min":288.71,"temp_max":294.26,"pressure":1028,"humidity":40},"wind":{"speed":0.89,"deg":190},"clouds":{"all":1},"dt":1587551663,"sys":{"type":3,"id":2006615,"country":"NO","sunrise":1587526916,"sunset":1587581574},"timezone":7200,"id":6453372,"name":"Drammen","cod":200}
```

how do I get the JSON data to appear in postman when I test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Postman is parsing/showing the correct value, as you are sending the url in the response.

To call an API within your code you need to use a HTTP Client/Handler. If you just assign the URL to a variable it will simply store it as a string and it is never going to call given url.

**RestTemplate** class (available by default in Spring, no other dependency required) is a simple HTTP client which allows to make API calls from within your code.
You can use RestTemplate to call the OpenWeather API and get the JSON response, the same response can be returned and viewed in Postman.

---

If you are sure that you are going to make only HTTP calls and no HTTPS, then follow approach 1 otherwise follow approach 2 -

Approach 1 :

```
@RestController
public class WeatherController{

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @GetMapping(value = "weather/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String getWeather(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        BreweriesGeocode geocode = geocode_service.getGeocode(id);
        Breweries brewerie = breweries_service.getBrewerieById(id);

        double latitude = geocode.getLatitude();
        double longitude = geocode.getLongitude();
        String url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+latitude+"&lon="+longitude+"&appid=4a1f5501b2798f409961c62d384a1c74";

        //Calling OpenWeather API
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
        String output = response.getBody();
        return output;
    }
}
```

Approach 2 :

```
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;

import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustStrategy;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Component
public class CustomRestTemplate {

    /**
     * @param isHttpsRequired - pass true if you need to call a https url, otherwise pass false
     */
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate(boolean isHttpsRequired)
            throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {

        // if https is not required,
        if (!isHttpsRequired) {
            return new RestTemplate();
        }

        // else below code adds key ignoring logic for https calls
        TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;
        SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy)
                .build();

        SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(csf).build();

        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);       
        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

Then in the controller class you can do as below-

```
@RestController
public class WeatherController{


    @Autowired
    CustomRestTemplate customRestTemplate;

    @GetMapping(value = "weather/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String getWeather(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        BreweriesGeocode geocode = geocode_service.getGeocode(id);
        Breweries brewerie = breweries_service.getBrewerieById(id);

        double latitude = geocode.getLatitude();
        double longitude = geocode.getLongitude();
        String url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+latitude+"&lon="+longitude+"&appid=4a1f5501b2798f409961c62d384a1c74";

        // Getting instance of Rest Template
        // Passing true becuase the url is a HTTPS url
        RestTemplate restTemplate = customRestTemplate.getRestTemplate(true);

        //Calling OpenWeather API
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);

        String output = response.getBody();

        return output;
    }
}
```

You can write a Http Error Handler for the RestTemplate reponses if reponse code is not a success code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the HTTP doesn't need to be HTTPS, so to avoid adding unnecessary dependencies, how do I alter the controller so it doesn't need to use the customRestTemplate?

Comment: @GreyWolf18 We don't need any dependency for RestTemplate, it is available by default in Spring.

Comment: Also, you cannot call an api by just assigning the url to a string variable. You need some HTTP Client/Handler in your code that will make a call to the api using the url. The same way, RestTemplate class gives readymade http client where you just need to call the url using it.

Comment: I understand I don't need a dependency for RestTemplate, however in the customRestTemplate, I am unable to add TrustStrategy, SSLContext, HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory and a few others, I assumed that a dependency was needed, what is a way around this?

Comment: @GreyWolf18 I have updated the answer, if you are sure you are only going to use Http then follow approach 1, it is small, clean and understandable. It will be enough to make an api call.

Comment: thanks, i think about autowireing the RestTemplate, sorry for the questions

Comment: Ya, the RestTemplate is Autowired. Any difficulties in understanding?

Answer (score 1):

I tested the URL in postman, it returns the correct response.
Check the below screen maybe you're doing something different.
[image: Postman response]

Make sure there are no spaces in url, i see the url you used in Postman had space after the ":"

Comment: Ya i realised the space after the http, sorry, i forgot to mention that i am testing the path http://localhost:8080/Assignment2C/map/weather/4 and how to search the browser using postman by calling my API

Comment: This is your local environment, i can't access that, but i hope my answer helped you